# push to git remote repo using a local copy

Tags: git, init

Given an existing private remote repository, to which I have access to, which contains only a README.md and a .gitingore file. Lets call this repo "myRepo".

Locally on my machine, I created a folder "myRepo", added some files to it and want to push everything to the remote "myRepo".

I am aware of the `git init` command. I would probably have to do `git remote add "url_to_myRepo"` then. Is this the right way to go?

And, my local folder contains a whole bunch of files which I do not want to be tracked by git. Do I have to create a .gitignore file before I do `git init`, or can I do it also afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `git init` just creates a local repository directory.  Then as @jim-redmond advised you should run `git remote add origin $URL`, then `git pull` to get your local repository synced with the remote.
Then, you then need to `git add` files.  You can add individual files explicitly with that command, but if you are going to add directories, you should probably have the .gitignore file created first.  Then of course you need to `git commit` to have the files actually saved into the repository.  Then you can run `git push` to save your committed files to the remote repository.

Comment: Better to run `git init`, then `git remote add origin $URL`, then `git pull` to fetch the existing content, and *then* `git add` and `git commit`. Otherwise there'll be an error when trying to push or pull, because the local and remote commits will be unrelated.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Malcolm!

OP: if the repo already exists elsewhere then `git clone` will do the directory creation, `git init`, `git remote add origin $URL`, and `git pull` steps in one command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `git remote add origin <url_of_the_repo>`, and then you can do `git push origin` to push local changes to the remote repo.

If you don't want to track certain files in your local folder, list them in `.gitignore`. This way, git will ignore them and won't bother you that you have uncommitted changes.

EDIT: You need to commit your changes first using the `git add` / `git commit` commands.

Comment: This won't do anything if the OP hasn't committed

Comment: This confirmes my suspicion. And as for my second question regarding the .gitignore?

Comment: `.gitignore` should come after `git init` but before adding any files.